# Sql deleting orphan records with composite primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

The table has a composite key with both source and target

```
source    target
 1        2
 2        3
 2        4
 3       -1
 4       -1
```

I wanted to delete records with the target value -1 and the source should not be in the target. In order to achieve the same, I'm using two different queries to delete the relevant records.

**Delete relationships**

> Deleting a record(on the above-mentioned sample) with value 2 in source and target would result in an
> empty table.

Entries with `-1` as target value and source value are not being referred in any other record then consider as orphan record and delete.

Is there a better way to delete it?

Comment: What is the expected output here?

Comment: I am confused in 'I wanted to delete records with the target value -1' seems to conflict with  'delete from test.orphan_table where source = 2 or target = 2;'

Comment: I have added more information to the question

Comment: As @P.Salmon said you doing the opposite, it's quite confusing

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: you want to delete all rows with target = -1 and then recursively all rows that have targets whose sources are deleted in previous steps?

Comment: What you're asking is not clear, do you need a query that does the work of "Query 1" and "Query 2" together? Just "Query 2"? If the latter, why did you share "Query 1", with its output, as it just confuse us more than help us? It would be preferable to have a relevant test case for "Query 2" only (with its output) then..

Comment: I have rephrased and simplified the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
delete t
from tablename t
where
  t.target = -1
  and 
  t.source not in (
    select target from (
      select target from tablename t
    ) b
  )
```

deletes all rows with `target = 1` unless `source` is included in any row in the `target` column. 
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w9FZdo4NjiN3FK7vVWekxq/2).
For this sample data:

```
| source | target |
| ------ | ------ |
| 1      |  2     |
| 2      |  3     |
| 3      |  4     |
| 3      | -1     |
| 4      | -1     |
| 5      | -1     |
```

only the last row will be deleted.